# How to access GCP source repository from private VM?

Tags: git, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to access GCP source repos from a private VM. I have tried using VPC service connect and "private service access". But it just times out. Is there any way to clone a source repository on private VM?

Comment: Do you have a NAT Gateway setup in your VPC?. I do not recall if `Private Google Access` supports Cloud Source Repositories. https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/private-access-options

Answer (score 2):

Cloud Source repositories are not APIs endpoints; but "internet" services.

In order to get access from your private compute instance, you must first access to `source.developers.google.com` in your VPC firewall rules.

If you are not allowed to do that (due to regulatory issues, for example), then you could use a f1-micro instance as proxy for your private instance (btw: a crazy idea could be configure SSH tunneling to map `localhost:443` to `source.developers.google.com:443`, setting your git remote to `localhost:443/p/[PROJECT_ID]/r/[REPO_NAME]`, and using a [git hook](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) to connect via ssh to the proxy).